# How to conditionally set input tag's max value base on a value of a Angular component's variable

Tags: html, angular

I have 3-way input control is defined as following

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="2" formControlName="dhwOption" class="form-control-range" style="width:180px" id="myonoffswitch2">
```

I would like to dynamically set the range from 2 to 1 using a component class variable's value, it does not work

```
 <input type="range" min="0" max= {*ngIf="appEngineMsg && appEngineMsg.Type === 0"}?"1" :"2" formControlName="dhwOption" class="form-control-range"
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the braces and quotes and try the following code, assuming appEngineMsg is a variable in the `.ts`

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="appEngineMsg && appEngineMsg.Type === 0 ? 1 : 2" formControlName="dhwOption" class="form-control-range"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [property binding syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-property) and take advantage of the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator):

```
[max]="appEngineMsg?.Type === 0 ? 1 : 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution for my own project

```
<input type="range" min="0" max='{{appEngineMsg && appEngineMsg.Type === 0 ? 1 : 2}}'>
```